# Can I force AWS to reinitialise my autoscaled instance daily maintaining a minimum of 1 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I've got an AWS autoscaling configuration and a launch schedule that says to keep a minimum of 1 all day. I'd like to flush out this instance and get a new one every day. I'd like to maintain a minimum of 1 all day. Is this possible?

My question is: **Can I force AWS to reinitialise my autoscaled instance daily maintaining a minimum of 1 instance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick with this is to have at least two - (or three) schedule windows.

We had

- High - 4 instances of this type (7am Weekendays)
- Low - 1 instance of this type (12.02pm every day)
- Recycle - 0 instance of this type (12pm every day)

The two-minute window with 0 isntances forces AWS to delete them and create fresh ones every day.